# Why does OpenJPA complain about "unexpected end of statement" when using EXISTS clause in named native query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I have a `@NamedNativeQuery` in `Hibernate`, which works fine:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT (ui.user_id) FROM USERS_INSTITUTION ui, USERS u WHERE u.id = ui.user_id AND ui.INSTITUTION_ID = ?1 AND u.username = ?2)
```

However, I am required to port this query to `OpenJPA`. Sadly, this results in an exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: unexpected end of statement in statement [SELECT EXISTS (SELECT (ui.user_id) FROM USERS_INSTITUTION ui, USERS u WHERE u.id = ui.user_id AND ui.INSTITUTION_ID = ? AND u.username = ?)] {SELECT EXISTS (SELECT (ui.user_id) FROM USERS_INSTITUTION ui, USERS u WHERE u.id = ui.user_id AND ui.INSTITUTION_ID = ? AND u.username = ?)} [code=-5590, state=42590]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:199) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:58) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection.prepareStatement(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:252) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:138) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.prepareStatement(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:144) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:138) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$RefCountConnection.prepareStatement(JDBCStoreManager.java:1695) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:127) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:517) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:497) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:486) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SQLStoreQuery$SQLExecutor.prepareStatement(SQLStoreQuery.java:310) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SQLStoreQuery$SQLExecutor.executeQuery(SQLStoreQuery.java:217) ~[openjpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    ... 59 more
```

My questions are:

- What am I missing here?
- Is this related to the JPA specification?
- Am I not allowed to use `EXISTS` with a sub select in OpenJPA?

**UPDATE / SOLUTION / CONTEXT**

I was working in a JUnit test setup using `HSQLDB`. In my `Hibernate` version, I did specify `sql.syntax_pgs=true` in the connection property. However, I missed this part in the `OpenJPA` implementation. Without this property, `HSQLDB` does not understand the related sql statement.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: The exception occurs in the JUnit Test Setup. It is HSQLDB.

Comment: Thanks @SternK. You pointed by into the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue originated from my JUnit test setup in combination with `HSQLDB`.

In my `Hibernate` environment, I was using `sql.syntax_pgs=true` with `HSQLDB`. However, I missed that part in my `OpenJPA` environment.

It seems, that `HSQLDB` does not support `SELECT EXISTS(...)` clauses without `sql.syntax_pgs=true` resulting in the exception listed above.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to enable sql logging to see the actual query issues to the JDBC driver statement?

Also looks like an exception under jpa layer (either jdbc pool or the driver) so checking the actually sent statement will likely give back the issue if openjpa rewrote it (shouldn't) or not.

Side note: you can likely do the same with hibernate to compare ;).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It pointed me to the right thing. There was a missing "sql.syntax_pgs=true" for the HSQLDB datasource configuration.